# Univariate Regression without intercept in Julia

Tags: julia

I can run a multivariate regression with:

```
using GLM
using Random
obs = 1000000
X = rand(obs)
y = X .+ rand(Normal(),obs) .+ 7
fit(LinearModel, rand(obs,2), y)
```

but I cannot seem to run a univariate regression as

```
fit(LinearModel, X, y)
```

results in a method error as `X` is not a matrix.

I could run a regression with an intercept by using:

```
fit(LinearModel, hcat(ones(obs),X), y)
```

**How can I run a univariate regression without an intercept in Julia?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case you are asking about the simplest way is to cast `X` to a `Matrix`, using:

```
fit(LinearModel, hcat(X), y)
```

or

```
fit(LinearModel, reshape(X, obs, 1), y)
```

Also in this case simply writing:

```
X\y
```

will give you a desired answer without using GLM (but you will only get the estimate in this case).